# routing rtmp ect streams via ffmpeg+python is it possible?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, mixing

Is it possible to solve this problem using ffmpeg+python or in conjunction with another solution.
I need a server solution, so Vmix, obs, etc are not suitable. (
eg: I have two (and/or more) streams

```
rtmp://host/live/input_stream_1
rtmp://host address/live/input_stream_2
 etc.
```

Is it possible to organize "routing" of streams (choosing a priority live-video-stream and applying layers to them according to the logic

- The logic of the layers might be like:[image]:

There is `input_stream_1` - it is default and local - videos from a network folder are packed via ffmpeg and fly to `rtmp://host address/live/output_stream_1A` (+ overlay layers -ect logos).

It is necessary, when an incoming stream `input_stream_2` appears, to replace the content of `input_stream_1` with the content of `input_stream_2` and send it, and when `input_stream_2` stops, going to return `input_stream_1` ?

Maybe it will be a combination of ffmpeg ([as suggested in this thread](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33984/combine-mp4-video-and-a-rtmp-stream-into-1-rtmp-output-stream-via-ffmpeg) [and in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278415/how-to-sync-multiple-rtsp-inputs-in-ffmpeg)) and [python solutions](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).